Opening the xivlauncher application causes the alt key to be held. How do you fix this?
I downloaded an app (xivlauncher - game launcher for Final Fantasy XIV on linux) from the discover store. I have also tried directly from flathub since it is a flatpak.
When I open it, it causes my whole computer to "freeze".
I have figured out that this "freezing" is actually it simulating the alt key being held (which I figured out due to having the alt key being bound to moving windows).
When the game crashed and when I deliberately terminated it, the computer goes back to normal after about 12 seconds.
I've contacted the developers and they haven't responded yet, but I think that this is something I'd be able to fix myself if I had more knowledge on apps and how to modify them.
The alt key doesn't need to be used in the app so if there is a way to just disable the key being used that would be a sufficient answer, at least for now. However, in key tests the key isn't actually being held, it just seems to be the "effect" of it.
Linux Mint 22 - Wilma, did not happen last time I installed linux which was a previous version of Linux Mint (21 or 22),
I've been told the flatpak version has issues due to an update upstream but not the issues I'm mentioning, and also the flatpak is the recommended official version, and also the only one I can use.

Please add more details what file exactly you downloaded from where, how you installed and ran the app. Does the problem go away when you terminate the app? [Edit] your question to add requested information.

@Bodo I've done this now, which I've edited into the post. Just so you don't have to reread it, XIVLauncher (a flatpak app used to launch Final Fantasy XIV on linux, downloaded from both the Discover store and Flathub) and yes it does go away when I terminate the app.

Please add links.

@Bodo I've put a hyperlink to the flatpak (same file as on the discover store), are there any more I should put here?
